# Texture Atlases In Corona SDK and Retina/Multi-res

Tags: coronasdk

I tried to find more information in the online docs, but they are still a bit lacking on this regard.

What is the proper way to handle multiple resolutions with the new texture atlas API? Should I provide a different data file for each resolution? Will Corona SDK find automatically the correct file or do I need to handle the resolution detection by myself?

Even just a pointer to a doc page where this is applied would be enough!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corona will load the image file (.png or .jpg) correctly, and will load the sheet file manually and then scale it...

If you are having difficulty making a sheet file that work in all resolutions, a good way is load manually the sheet correct for that resolution, and then use .xScale and .yScale to correct the resolution.

I will post my own resolution handling code for Atlas:

```
-- Mauricio Gomes
-- Kidoteca point class

local scaleString = "";
local scaleNumber = 1;
local errorMessage = "ERROR: Please call autoResolution.init";
local errorFunction = function() print(errorMessage); return errorMessage end;

local autoResolution = {};

function autoResolution.requireSheet( sheet )
    if autoResolution.SCALE == errorFunction then
        return errorFunction();
    end
    sheet = string.gsub(sheet, "/", ".");
    return require(sheet .. scaleString).sheet;
end

function autoResolution.requireInfo( sheet )
    if autoResolution.SCALE == errorFunction then
        return errorFunction();
    end
    sheet = string.gsub(sheet, "/", ".");
    return require(sheet .. scaleString);
end

function autoResolution.imageName( fileName, extension )
    if autoResolution.SCALE == errorFunction then
        return errorFunction();
    end
    return fileName .. scaleString .. "." .. extension;
end

-- variables about the scale settings

function autoResolution.init()
    if display.contentScaleX <= 0.25 then
        scaleString = "@4";
        scaleNumber = 0.25;
    elseif display.contentScaleX <= 0.7 then
        scaleString = "@2";
        scaleNumber = 0.5;
    end

    autoResolution.SCALE = scaleNumber;
end

autoResolution.SCALE = errorFunction;

return autoResolution;
```

The init function of course use the settings my company (Kidoteca) use: suffixes being @2 and @4, and not exactly 0.5 being @2 because some internal reasons of ours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, I saw it only now! Not sure why but it won't give me permissions to +1 your answer!